# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paths'

Tags: python, path, package, pythonpath

I'm having a problem in modules, so I'm trying to make a package in python and publish it. When I install my package it's saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'x'`. I don't know what the problem is since the path is correct.

This is my `__init__.py` code:

```py
from ordinal import ordinal
from ordinal_letters import ordinal_letters
from randomNumber import randomNumber
from randomString import randomString
```

The error is coming from the `__init__` file. What is the problem there?

Here's my path:

```
Voider-Python  --> Base
└── voider   --> Actual Module
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── ordinal_letters.py
    ├── ordinal.py
    ├── randomNumber.py
    ├── randomString.py
```

I literally don't know what's the problem, since it's the correct path.

Comment: We need to see more parts of the code.
Where is the code you are calling from located?
How did you init the module?

Comment: That's only the code tho. But do you mean "ill show all the code"?

Comment: check the import statements in all the .py files and look if you have made an incorrect import somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I install my package"? The code we need to see is the code that causing the error message (and an indication of where the its `.py` file is relative to your file and folder structure).